# Flutter iOS: Unable to install FBSDKMarketingKit

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, fbsdk

I am upgrading to latest Facebook SDK, following the guidelines and when I run pod update I get the following error about not being able to resolve `host: origincache.facebook.com`

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing AppAuth (1.5.0)
Installing Bolts (1.9.1)
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.24)
Installing FBAEMKit (13.2.0)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (13.2.0)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (13.2.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (13.2.0)
Installing FBSDKMarketingKit (4.38.0)

[!] Error installing FBSDKMarketingKit
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/tg/wkq_y0195v5fkm57j908f33h0000gn/T/d20220703-51482-10hvmb9/file.zip https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.38.0.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.11.3 cocoapods-downloader/1.4.0'

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: origincache.facebook.com
Warning: Problem : timeout. Will retry in 1 seconds. 2 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: origincache.facebook.com
Warning: Problem : timeout. Will retry in 2 seconds. 1 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: origincache.facebook.com
```

Flutter doctor output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.3, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

My setup:
XCode v13.4.1
MacOS 12.4 (Monterey), Intel

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

adding
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'

in ios/Pod file
Reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/platform-setup/ios/add-sdk

Comment: The issue is with FBSDKMarketingKit. I cannot install it: `Could not resolve host: origincache.facebook.com`

Comment: Yes, mainly through a thorough and tedious update of everything... MacOS, Xcode, Flutter, pods etc.